# Wordpress get custom post type list without parent

Tags: wordpress, list, post, paging

I've got a worpress with custom post type recipe, I order the post by making a parent post for kind of recipe (like fish) and than I make the post with the recipe.

I'd like to make a list of all the post but without the parent pages. There not that much problem with that, but I need to get a paging that will work with that. Is it possible?

I tried listing all the post and just skip the parent page but the pagination doesn't work with it.

Any idea?

Thanks for the help in advance.

here is the code

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'recipe', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
       $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'recipe',
               'post_parent' => $post->ID
       );

       $hasChildQ = new WP_Query( $args );

       if( !$hasChildQ->have_posts() ){ 
          get_template_part( 'content', 'recipe' ); 
       }
    endwhile; // end of the loop. 
?>
```

But I would like it to be done in the main query so that the paging will work with it
any suggestion would be nice.

Comment: We will need some code to look at to better assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making that parent page a custom taxonomy. 
That way you could query by taxonomy.

So your Recipe would be a CPT, but your recipe category would a 'Recipe Type' taxonomy.

Online help:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies
- http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-taxonomy/

-d

Comment: Thank, I didn't know what was taxonomies I really appreciate the quick answer :)